# Record and download the video of a client using their stream or canvas

Tags: reactjs, node.js, canvas, stream, webrtc

I'm trying to record and download the live video of a client using canvas or their stream

Code below:

```js
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', handleSourceOpen, false);
let mediaRecorder = []; // this is an array because i will have multiple media recorders for multiple clients
let recordedBlobs = []; // this is an array because i will have multiple recorded blobs for multiple clients
let sourceBuffer = []; // this is an array because i will have multiple source buffers for multiple clients

let recording = false;

let canvasArray = [{
    username: "",
    socketId: "",
    canvas: null
}];
let streams = [{
    username: "",
    socketId: "",
    stream: null
}];

function setStream() {
    console.log(connections)
    for (let i = 1; i < canvasArray.length; i++) {

        console.log(canvasArray[i].username, canvasArray[i].socketId, canvasArray[i].canvas, canvasArray[i].clstream);
        console.log("canvasArray", canvasArray);

        streams.push({
            username: canvasArray[i].username,
            socketId: canvasArray[i].socketId,
            stream: canvasArray[i].canvas
        });
        console.log('Started stream capture from canvas element: ', streams[i].stream, streams[i].username, streams[i].socketId);

        console.log("hi", connections[canvasArray[i].socketId].getLocalStreams())
    }

    console.log("streams", streams);
    console.log("canvasArray", canvasArray);
}

function handleSourceOpen(event, username) {
    console.log('MediaSource opened for: ', username);
    sourceBuffer = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < streams.length; i++) {
        sourceBuffer.push(mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vp9"'));
        console.log('Source buffer: ', sourceBuffer[i]);
    }
}

function handleDataAvailable(event, socketId, username) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        for (let i = 1; i < streams.length; i++) {
            if (streams[i].socketId === socketId) {
                recordedBlobs[i].push(event.data);
                console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log("For socketId: ", socketId, "with username: ", username, "recordedBlobs", recordedBlobs);
    } else {
        console.log('No data available');
    }
}


function startRecording() {
    const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs: "vp9"' };

    for (let i = 1; i < streams.length; i++) {
        const username = streams[i].username;
        const socketId = streams[i].socketId;

        // Check if there's an existing MediaRecorder and stop it
        if (mediaRecorder[i] && mediaRecorder[i].state !== 'inactive') {
            mediaRecorder[i].stop();
        }

        console.log('Started stream capture from canvas element:', username, socketId);
        
        if (streams[i].stream) {
            recordedBlobs[i] = [];
            try {
                console.log("streams[i].stream", streams[i].stream);
                mediaRecorder[i] = new MediaRecorder(streams[i].stream, options);
                console.log('Created MediaRecorder', mediaRecorder[i], 'with options', options);
                mediaRecorder[i].onstop = handleStop;
                mediaRecorder[i].ondataavailable = (event) => handleDataAvailable(event, socketId, username);

                try {
                    mediaRecorder[i].start(100); // collect 100ms of data
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error('Exception while starting MediaRecorder:', e);
                    alert('Exception while starting MediaRecorder: ' + e + '.\n\n' +
                        'See console logs for more details.');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('MediaRecorder started', mediaRecorder[i]);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder:', e);
                alert('MediaRecorder is not supported by this browser.\n\n' +
                    'Try Firefox 29 or later, or Chrome 47 or later, ' +
                    'with Enable experimental Web Platform features enabled from chrome://flags.');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}


function handleStop(event) {
    console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
}

function stopRecording() {
    for (let i = 0; i < mediaRecorder.length; i++) {
        if (mediaRecorder[i]) {
            mediaRecorder[i].stop();
            console.log('Recorded Blobs: ', recordedBlobs[i]);
        }
    }
}

function download() {
    for (let i = 1; i < recordedBlobs.length; i++) {
        const blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs[i], { type: 'video/webm' });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = `${streams[i].username}.webm`;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 100);
        break;
    }
    console.log("recordedBlobs", recordedBlobs);
}
```

this is on top of my component

```js
socket.on('user-joined', (id, clients, connectionsWithNames) => {
                clients.forEach((socketListId) => {
                    connections[socketListId] = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig)
                    // Wait for their ice candidate       
                    connections[socketListId].onicecandidate = function (event) {
                        if (event.candidate != null) {
                            socket.emit('signal', socketListId, JSON.stringify({ 'ice': event.candidate }))
                        }
                    }

                    // Wait for their video stream
                    connections[socketListId].onaddstream = (event) => {
                        var searchVidep = document.querySelector(`[data-socket="${socketListId}"]`)
                        if (searchVidep !== null) {
                            searchVidep.srcObject = event.stream
                        } else {
                            elms = clients.length
                            let main = document.getElementById('main')
                            let cssMesure = changeCssVideos({ main, elms });

                            let videoWrapper = document.createElement('div')
                            let video = document.createElement('video')

                            videoWrapper.id = socketListId
                            videoWrapper.className = "videoWrapper"

                            const idDisplay = document.createElement('div');
                            idDisplay.innerText = connectionsWithNames[socketListId];

                            videoWrapper.style.display = "flex";
                            videoWrapper.style.flexDirection = "column";
                            videoWrapper.style.justifyContent = "flex-start";
                            videoWrapper.style.alignItems = "flex-start";
                            videoWrapper.style.position = "relative";
                            videoWrapper.style.zIndex = "1";

                            idDisplay.style.position = "absolute";
                            idDisplay.style.top = "0px";
                            idDisplay.style.left = "0px";
                            idDisplay.style.zIndex = "2";
                            idDisplay.style.padding = "5px";
                            idDisplay.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
                            idDisplay.style.color = "white";
                            idDisplay.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                            idDisplay.style.fontSize = "10px";


                            let css = {
                                minWidth: cssMesure.minWidth,
                                minHeight: cssMesure.minHeight,
                                maxHeight: "100%",
                                margin: "10px",
                                borderStyle: "solid",
                                borderColor: "#bdbdbd",
                                objectFit: "fill"
                            }

                            for (let prop in css) {
                                videoWrapper.style[prop] = css[prop];
                            }
                            videoWrapper.style.setProperty("width", cssMesure.width)
                            videoWrapper.style.setProperty("height", cssMesure.height)

                            // for (let i in css) video.style[i] = css[i]
                            // video.style.setProperty("width", cssMesure.width)
                            // video.style.setProperty("height", cssMesure.height)

                            video.style.width = "100%";
                            video.style.height = "100%";
                            video.style.objectFit = "fill";
                            // add classname to video element
                            video.className = `client-video-${socketListId}`

                            video.setAttribute('data-socket', socketListId)
                            video.srcObject = event.stream
                            video.autoplay = true
                            video.playsinline = true

                            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                            canvas.style.width = "100%"
                            canvas.style.height = "100%"
                            video.style.objectFit = "fill";
                            canvas.style.position = "absolute";
                            canvas.style.top = "0px";
                            canvas.style.left = "0px";
                            canvas.style.zIndex = "3";
                            canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none";
                            // canvas.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                            canvas.className = "clientcanvas";

                            canvasArray.push({
                                username: connectionsWithNames[socketListId],
                                socketId: socketListId,
                                // canvas: canvas.captureStream(25).getVideoTracks()[0],/
                                // i dont want tracts i want the stream
                                canvas: canvas.captureStream(25),
                                // but then the stread doesnt have handleDataAvailable function
                                // so i need to add the handleDataAvailable function to the stream
                                // but how do i do that?

                                clstream: connections[socketListId].getLocalStreams()[0] // this is the stream of the user who joined the call
                            });
                            console.log("canvasArray", canvasArray);
                            
                            videoWrapper.appendChild(idDisplay);
                            videoWrapper.appendChild(canvas);
                            videoWrapper.appendChild(video)
                            main.appendChild(videoWrapper)

                            setStream();
                        }
                    }

                    // Add the local video stream
                    if (window.localStream !== undefined && window.localStream !== null) {
                        connections[socketListId].addStream(window.localStream)
                    } else {
                        let blackSilence = (...args) => new MediaStream([black(...args), silence()])
                        window.localStream = blackSilence()
                        connections[socketListId].addStream(window.localStream)
                    }
                })

                if (id === socketId) {
                    for (let id2 in connections) {
                        if (id2 === socketId) continue

                        try {
                            connections[id2].addStream(window.localStream)
                        } catch (e) { }

                        connections[id2].createOffer().then((description) => {
                            connections[id2].setLocalDescription(description)
                                .then(() => {
                                    socket.emit('signal', id2, JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': connections[id2].localDescription }))
                                })
                                .catch(e => console.log(e))
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
```

and this is where im adding the clstream to the canvasArray

now if i use the stream instead of canvas

```js
streams.push({
            username: canvasArray[i].username,
            socketId: canvasArray[i].socketId,
            stream: canvasArray[i].clstream
        });
```

1. the code works properly but it downloads its own stream video and not of the client
   i dont know what im doing wrong even tho clstream is the stream of the client
2. if i use the canvas

```js
                            canvasArray.push({
                                username: connectionsWithNames[socketListId],
                                socketId: socketListId,
                                canvas: canvas.captureStream(25).getVideoTracks()[0],
                                clstream: connections[socketListId].getLocalStreams()[0] // this is the stream of the user who joined the call
                            });
```

it returns CanvasCaptureMediaStreamTrack thus its not a media stream and the recordinf , downloading doesnt work

idk what i am doing wrong
so any help would be appreciated , Thank you